# haskell-stack command with GHC option

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm using `stack` command to compile a Haskell code. I'd like to compile with GHC options like `-O2`. I would like you tell how do I do this.

The following command is not OK. I'd like to do like the below code.

```
stack ghc -O2 hello.hs
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of GHC specific options should be placed after `--`

ex.

```
stack ghc -- -O2 hello.hs
```